# Is it possible to write a jest unit test in node for a promise with no catch block?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga

**What's the problem**

I'm trying to write a basic react django boilerplate with user login. I'm handling the login flow with `react-saga`.

I have a saga which calls a login function, which pings the server and gets a token. The saga handles all the error handling. If that call fails the error is successfully returned to react and shown to the user. It works correctly.

I'm trying to write a unit test for the login function. I think node is catching my error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

I guess because saga catches it in reality, node doesn't throw that error.

Does that mean I can't unit test that the login function should throw an uncaught error?

Should I just not bother testing this?

**Code**

This is the function that calls the server.

```
 # Auth login function

login(email, password) {
    // If user is already logged in return true.
    if (auth.loggedIn()) return Promise.resolve(true);
    const credentials = btoa(`${email}:${password}`);
    // Request to login
    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${SERVER_URL}/api/v1/accounts/login/`,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        // Save token to local storage
        if (response.data.token) {
            localStorage.auth_token = response.data.token;
        } else {
            // To Do-- throw error if server fails to return one
        }
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Then this is the saga which is handling the logic.

```
export function* authorize({
    email,
    password,
    isRegistering,
    firstName,
    lastName
}) {
    // We send an action that tells Redux we're sending a request
    yield put({ type: SENDING_REQUEST, sending: true });

    // We then try to register or log in the user, depending on the request
    try {
        let response;

        // For either log in or registering, we call the proper function in the `auth`
        // module, which is asynchronous. Because we're using generators, we can work
        // as if it's synchronous because we pause execution until the call is done
        // with `yield`!
        if (isRegistering) {
            response = yield call(
                register,
                email,
                password,
                firstName,
                lastName
            );
        } else {
            response = yield call(login, email, password);
        }

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        // If we get an error we send Redux the appropriate action and return
        yield put({
            type: REQUEST_ERROR,
            error: error.response.data,
            sending: false
        });

        return false;
    } finally {
        // When done, we tell Redux we're not in the middle of a request any more
        yield put({ type: SENDING_REQUEST, sending: false });
    }
}
```

Then this is my unit test:

```
describe("login function", () => {
    let mock;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        localStorage.clear();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // We need to clear mocks
        // and remove tokens from local storage to prevent
        // us from staying logged in
        mock.restore();
    });

    test("Check that exception thrown on server error", () => {
        // Mock loggedin function to throw error
        mock.onPost().reply(500);
        Test that error is uncaught.
        expect(() => {
            auth.login("test@example.com", "pass").then(value => {
                console.log(value);
            });
        }).toThrow();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it. `toThrow` method is used to catch thrown errors, but promise rejects errors therefore require different API to be used. To catch your error `.rejects.toThrow();` as well you should `await` for the expect block to finish resulting in:

```
describe("login function", () => {
    let mock;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        localStorage.clear();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // We need to clear mocks
        // and remove tokens from local storage to prevent
        // us from staying logged in
        mock.restore();
    });

    test("Check that exception thrown on server error", async () => {
        // Mock loggedin function to throw error
        mock.onPost().reply(500);
        Test that error is uncaught.
        await expect(() => auth.login("test@example.com", "pass")).rejects.toThrow(); // add an error message to check for correct error
    });
});
```

PS. This is well documented in [jest API docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects).

Comment: `() => ` should be omitted, since `login` doesn't actually throw.